# Converting DTO to Entity Manually

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new here and also new in this developer world! I started my studies in the beginning of this year and now I am trying to do a very simple Spring Boot API REST project. However I'm not getting how can I convert DTO to an Entity and then return it to the Controller.

I'd like to make a Mapper Class to do this work and not using a library for this, but rather do it manually(I know that is not the simplest way, but it's just for my apprenticeship). Then pass it to the Service and then to the Controller. Is that right?

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: You should share some code, so that your concrete problem gets more clear. Otherwise I could just recommend to google for Spring Boot tutorials with REST API - there are a lot.

Comment: Do you have any code? First, start programming, then, share your contoller, service, dto and entity code so we can help you.

Comment: Yeah.. I've watched some tutorials, but I was still having some problems in converting my Entity to DTO and returning to Controller... I'm gonna try to reorganize again and check if it will work. One way or another I'll post my code here for you to help me improve some things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not getting how can I convert DTO to an Entity and then return it
> to the Controller.

-> It is not a good design to expose the entity to the end user. You must convert that entity to a dto and then share it with the end user in case it is required.

This is a sample design that you can use.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Gurkirat! This design cleared my mind. I will reorganize my codes here.